# Team Project and Work Areas - only one iteration and burndown active

Tags: tfs

I'm struggling getting my two development teams, both working on the same project (code base) but running separate weekly sprints to each have there own burndown or active iteration.

I have two separate delivery teams (team1 and team2) 
Both run weekly sprints (5 days) - team1 iteration is Monday through Friday, team2 iteration is Tuesday through Monday. 
I created one team Project called Project X and one team Area called Project X with two child items (team1 and team2) 
I'm using the Agile process template

In the Work module I see team1 as the Current Sprint and all is a success, Use Stores, Planning, Tasking, Capacity, Burndown... BUT
team2 is showing as a Future iteration even though there iteration dates are today. It's Tuesday and team1 is on day 2 and team2 is on day one of there sprints.

I must have a concept problem. Is it even possible to have 2 iterations and burndown's going under one team project?
I appreciate your time, thanks.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two Teams, each with its own iteration and area. If you're seeing one team as being the "current" iteration and one team as being the "future" iteration, something is not configured correctly.

Iterations should look like this:

- Project Root

  - Team A

    - Iteration 1
    - Iteration 2
    - Iteration etc
  - Team B

    - Iteration 1
    - Iteration 2
    - Iteration etc

Areas should look like this:

- Team Project Root

  - Team A
  - Team B

Create two separate Teams, Team A and Team B. For each team, go to the Work configuration hub and choose the team's backlog iteration and which area it should use as its root. Then you can freely switch between teams to see their individual backlogs and burndowns.

Ref: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams